Does the extension of L3(5) in the Lyons group split
According to the ATLAS of Finite groups, the sporadic Lyons group has a subgroup 53.L3(5), and the notation specifies that this extension does not split. However, according to the Wikipedia page on the Dempwolff group, such an extension is impossible; the only nonsplit extensions of a linear group by its natural module are 23.L3(2), 24.A8, and 25.L5(2).
Obviously, these statements contradict one another, so my question is, does the extension 53.L3(5) split? This is probably easy to check computationally, but I don't have any experience with group theory software.

The subgroup you ask about is a nonsplit extension $5^3.\operatorname{PSL}_3(5)$, as indicated in the ATLAS, and can be verified computationally.
Unlike you claim, I don't see a statement that a nonsplit extension $5^3.PSL(3,5)$ is impossible in the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempwolff_group .
We can also use an argument I found on page 1198 of: "Woldar, A. J. (1987). On the maximal subgroups of lyons’ Group. Communications in Algebra, 15(6), 1195-1203.".
Proof that the extension is nonsplit: Since $Ly$ has $5$-rank equal to $3$, any extension $5^3.\operatorname{PSL}_3(5) = 5^3.\operatorname{SL}_3(5)$ must be nonsplit.
Indeed, in a split extension $5^3:\operatorname{SL}_3(5)$ you can find an elementary abelian $5$-subgroup of order $5^4$. For example $5^2:U = 5^4$, where $$U = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & * \\ 0 & 1 & * \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ and the $5^2$ factor is the fixed point space of $U$.
Well, we would still need to explain why $Ly$ has $5$-rank equal to $3$. There's probably some standard reference for this which I haven't attempted to find.

I figured out my mistake and clarified the Wikipedia page (a nonsplit extension by the general linear group is imposssible, but the special linear group is allowed).
To your question about the 5-rank, I would use the fact that the Syllow 2-supgroup of Ly is contained in the subgroup G2(5), then determine the 5-rank of this subgroup.

@CoreSilverman: Yes, that's a good approach - the $p$-ranks of groups of Lie type $G(p)$ can be found for example in Gorenstein-Lyons-Solomon CFSG volume 3. And indeed for $G_2(5)$ the $5$-rank is equal to $3$.
